# calculate some fields in array of objects from v-for with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new with Vue.js and i'm using a  `v-for` to iterate an array of objects, but i need to calculate a single field (`precoPorKg`) in this `v-for`.

to calculate this i need that input `item.quantidade` had some value and after this, i need to  make this operation:

`(item.quantidade * item.valorUnitario)/( item.quantidade * item.pesoUnitario)`

My `v-for`:

```
 <tr v-for="(item, index) in step2">
     <td>{{ item.produto }}</td>
     <td><input type="text" v-model="item.quantidade"></td>
     <td>{{ item.valorUnitario }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.pesoUnitario }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.cubagemUnitaria }}</td>
     <td>{{ calcPrecoPorKg(index, item) }}</td> 
 </tr>
```

my vue component (i'm trying to make this operation in computed, but doesn't work):

```
   new Vue({
                el: '#app', 
                data(){
                step2 : [
                  {
                    produto: 'A70-5',
                    descricao: 'bola de basquete',
                    ncm: '950.6',
                    quantidade: '',
                    valorUnitario: '0,78',
                    pesoUnitario: '0,430',
                    cubagemUnitaria: '0,00',
                    precoPorKg: '',
                  }
             ],
         computed: {
            calcPrecoPorKg: function (index, item) {
                return (item.quantidade * item.valorUnitario)/( item.quantidade * item.pesoUnitario);
                     }
                }

    })
```

Comment: Try making this a method rather than computed property and it should work

Comment: @Himanshu how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

computed properties do not take any parameters. What you need is just a method.

```
methods: {
  calcPrecoPorKg(item) {
    return (item.quantidade * item.valorUnitario)/( item.quantidade * item.pesoUnitario);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i changed to method and i was using wrong values to the operation, i correct this and it works! thanks